# Prevent a listView from rendering a partial list item

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list I am building as follows:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: items.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
      return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('${items.title}'),
        ],
      );
    }
  );
}
```

Is there a way to have the list only show full items and not allow for displaying a cut-off item (like in the image).

[image]

Comment: Your question is not easy to understand "only render full items and not allow for displaying a partial item unless the user scrolls"? this is a very confusing sentence. What is a full item? What is a partial item?

Comment: Can you add an image to show the final result you want?